# Excel Vba: Sub or Function not defined

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code

```
Sub CopyMacro()
'
' CopyData Macro
'
    Dim tableName As ListObject
    Set tableName = Worksheets("ToCopySheet").ListObjects(1)
    ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("TaskUID").DataBodyRange.Copy tableName.ListColumns("TaskUID").DataBodyRange

End Sub
```

When I try to run this I get a compile error. Sub or Function not defined. I do not understand the issue here as I don't see anything wrong in this syntax.

The thing I'm trying to accomplish is to copy one column from one table to another table column in another sheet (ToCopySheet).

Could someone please help resolve this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you mean

```
Sub CopyMacro()
'
' CopyData Macro
'
    Dim tableName As ListObject
    Set tableName = Worksheets("ToCopySheet").ListObjects(1)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("TaskUID").DataBodyRange.Copy tableName.ListColumns("TaskUID").DataBodyRange

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am getting a subscript out of range error when I use this code

Comment: I do not know your excel sheet but you need to have a table1 with a column TaskUID and on your second sheet "ToCopySheet" the first table should also contain a column "TaskUID"

Comment: no sorry, it was my mistake with the table names etc. now its resolved